# Unable to get friendList

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

```
var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters: nil);

request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println("Friends are : \(result)")
    } else {
        println("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
    }
```

-----------------------------------My log-------------------------

```
Friends are : {
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 714;
    };
}
```

How do i fetch the facebook friends of user who are using this app . Please help. Any help will be appreatiated . thankx in advance .

Comment: Is your friend list public??

Comment: yes my friend list is public .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly get the all friends from facebook because it won't allow these. But you can do with the following stuff however you won't be able to get facebook id for that friends you can get only names and profile pic

**Note : you need to get approval from facebook to use taggable_friends.**

```
var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/taggable_friends", parameters: nil);
```

You need to check as below for your permissions are granted successfully or not then you can check for the friends list.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
            || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended)
        {
            [self loadFacebookFriends];
        }
        else
        {
            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile,email,user_friends"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:
             ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (!error)
                 {
                     if (state == FBSessionStateOpen)
                     {
                         [FBSession setActiveSession:session];

                         [self loadFacebookFriends];

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Status :%ld",(unsigned long)state);
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     // Could not connect
                 }
             }];
        }
-(void)loadFacebookFriends
{
    // SEND REQUEST FOR FRIEND LISTs
    FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/friends"];
    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary* result,NSError *error)
     {
         [appDelegate activityHide];

         if (error)
         {
             return ;
         }

         NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
         NSLog(@"Found: %lu friends", (unsigned long)friends.count);
     }];
}
```

**Note : If you are using iOS 9  you need to give following permissions to your app in info.plist. You can also refer this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9
**

Add below Transport Securtiy in your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>graph.facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I only what the friends who are using the the app but unable to get friend list .

Comment: @SmitThakkar please check my edited answer. It may be helpful to you .

Comment: cool hopefully i am trying to understand but as it is in objective c it would be difficult . Anyways thankx for your help .

Answer (score 0):

According to latest sdk: This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends

Answer (score 0):

Latest FB SDK will not give access to fetch facebook friends who is not using your app. 
You will get list only those friends who are using your app.

Answer (score 0):

The another thing was that i didnt took permission well thankx for you help .